# Is there any option for setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a file continuously after a some time as

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON("json/someFile.json", function(data){
        // Some code
    });
}, 5000);
```

I am reading this file continuously after a delay as it is getting updated in other part of the code. I want to avoid using setInterval().

Is there any way, by which I will be able to know that the file is updated and read it only when it is updated.

Comment: `setInterval()` is not of `jQuery`..

Comment: You could use websockets instead, by making the server send a notification to the client when the file is changed.

Comment: I also suggest please use websockets, some useful link for websocket is:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: You are looking for server PUSH technology

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about client side code. Then **no: there is no way to "watch" a json file** like you could have a file watcher in "regular" applications. You need either:

- Interval-based checking as you're doing now. However, as suggested in comments by @George, you might be better off if you use `setTimeout` and only re-fire the Ajax request in specific situations (e.g. on success, perhaps *not* on failures); With your current approach the function may run on the interval, but if it takes longer than the interval timing to respond you get a build-up of requests;
- Websockets (potentially with fallback to something like long-polling), perhaps using another library for that + the server-side part of this solution;

No other way I'm afraid.

As a footnote, this hasn't got much to do with jQuery. First, the `setInterval` is not of jQuery but a regular `window` function, and second the problem of "watching" a file isn't specific to *how* you're doing the Ajax call (you're using jQuery, but you could use another lib for it too).

Comment: @George Good point. Added that to the first bullet. Feel free to suggest edits to the answer if I've missed details.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, setInterval is a native JavaScript method. It does not come from jQuery. Second what you've done is called polling. Meaning that you request some information periodically in order to keep it up to date. The alternative is using a WebSockets. Websockets are a two way connection between the client and the server, which can both push and receive messages. This way, you can send a socket message to the client whenever the file is updated in the backend.